Auto Hide Top Bar GNOME extension disables w button
When 'Auto Hide Top Bar' is enabled, the "w" button does not work. Is anyone else experiencing this issue? When I press "w" ,the top bar appears and then hides.
How to fix this?
This is the extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar

Which top bar? What do you mean by "" is enabled? Are you using Ubuntu?

Yes, i am using Ubuntu 22.04- When the (Auto Hide Top Bar ) on the Extension settings is enabled,(the Top Bar contain Power Date and Time Sound ..Etc)

Can you also add a link to this extension

yes,("https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/")

w button does not work anywhere, in any app?

google chrome ,Firefox etc

We need specific details. Does w work in the terminal? What about libreoffice? Or does it only not work in the web browsers?

for that ,it's a same problem "Not Working" but "W" capital is working

Please report the bug to the extension developer as well https://gitlab.gnome.org/tuxor1337/hidetopbar/-/issues

thanks bro for help
